# SQL Server Agent stopped unexpectedly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I have some issues with my SQL Server Agent, when I use my Visual Studio 2015 for a Winforms object, it count'd load the data from the database. When I check the SQL Server Agent through Services, it stopped automatically. I know that I have to set it to "Started", but after 2 or 3 minutes, ehe SQL Server Agent stopped unexpectedly. Can someone help me with that please?

Comment: Error log is the key.